# What is the right way to check mp.managers.DictProxy' size?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn multiprocessing and keep the memory usage low, so I'd like to check the size of my objects now and then.
I'm using a `mp.managers.DictProxy` to store results from multiple `mp.Process()` 'workers'(?) that put their results in an output `mp.Queue()`.

I tried to see what size the dictionary got, but it *kept* returning `56` when tried to test it.

**EDIT**: after testing it in python 3.9.7 (same device) the output now magically is `48`.

```py
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':   # needed if running on windows
    manager = mp.Manager()

    result_storage = manager.dict({k:k for k in range(100000)})

    print(sys.getsizeof(result_storage))
    # print USED to be 56 for me when i created this question
    # print is now 48 consistently. same device. I didn't record the previous python version
    # current python version is 3.9.7

    print(sys.getsizeof(result_storage.copy()))
    # prints 5242968
```

I've tried to `print(sys.getsizeof(result_storage.copy()))`. That returned <strike>`5242976`</strike>  `5242968`  Can I reliably use this to check the size or is there a better way? I've never used `.copy()` and I don't know what the impact is. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.copy) are beyond me.